# Case sensitive error with Oracle and SQLAlchemy join

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a Oracle 11g database which I query with SQLAlchemy 0.9.7 and my database has a table call gateway which has a primary key column called id_gateway which is case sensitive, so I have to query manually like this:

```
SELECT "id_gateway" FROM gateway;
```

And I have this query:

```
psp_data = query(
    default_forma_pago_web.id_gateway,
    psp_config.merchant_id,
    psp_config.merchant_id_sc,
    psp_config.email
    ).join(
    psp_config,
    psp_config.id_productora == default_forma_pago_web.id_productora
    ).join(
    gateway,
    gateway.id_gateway == default_forma_pago_web.id_gateway
    ).filter(
    default_forma_pago_web.id_productora == self.productora,
    default_forma_pago_web.id_forma_pago == self.medio_de_pago,
    default_forma_pago_web.cuotas == self.cuotas
    )
```

***Edited because I picked the wrong query.***

And I get this error:

```
*** sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00904: "GATEWAY"."ID_GATEWAY": invalid identifier
```

This is the schema of the tables:

```
class Gateway(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'gateway'

    id_gateway = Column(String(6), primary_key=True)
    url_produccion = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    url_implementacion = Column(String(255))
    lang_es = Column(String(5))
    lang_en = Column(String(5))

t_psp_config = Table(
    u'psp_config', metadata,
    Column(u'id', String(20), primary_key=True),
    Column(u'id_productora', ForeignKey(u'productora.id_productora'), nullable=False),
    Column(u'merchant_id', String(20)),
    Column(u'email', String(255)),
    Column(u'merchant_id_sc', String(20)),
    Column(u'id_gateway', String(6)),
    Column(u'debug', Numeric(1, 0, False)),
    Column(u'moneda', String(10)),
    Column(u'pais', String(20))
)

class DefaultFormaPagoWeb(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'default_forma_pago_web'
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [u'id_gateway', u'id_forma_pago'],
            [u'forma_pago_x_gateway.id_gateway', u'forma_pago_x_gateway.id_forma_pago']
            ),
    )

    id_forma_pago_web = Column(Numeric(scale=0, asdecimal=False), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    id_productora = Column(ForeignKey(u'productora.id_productora'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    id_forma_pago = Column(String(20), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    id_gateway = Column(String(20), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    cuotas = Column(Numeric(scale=0, asdecimal=False), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    diferencial = Column(Numeric(8, 2))
    es_porcentual = Column(Numeric(1, 0, False))

    forma_pago_x_gateway = relationship(u'FormaPagoXGateway')
    productora = relationship(u'Productora')
```

How do I join this table with the case sensitive column?

Comment: Can you show your code in which you describe tables and columns?

Comment: @yamny Done updating. Do you need any more info?